# GC Overhead limit exceeded error after program launch - no scripts running

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu-14.04

Matlab will start to consume more and more resources and eventually this error occurs.

```
Exception in thread "Explorer NavigationContext request queue" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.String.concat(Uknown Sourc)
    at com.matlab...
    at com.matlab... etc
Exception in thread "Explorer NavigationContext request queue"
```

I'm running matlab R2015a

I'm on ubuntu 14.04 LTS - i5-2430M CPU @ 2.4ghz x 4 500gb ssd 64bit

I get this error w/o running a single command. After launching matlab it spits this error out after about 30s of slowly consuming more and more resources. I can't figure this out and matlab hasn't responded to any of my posts.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100335-why-do-i-receive-an-error-when-i-execute-the-fetch-statement-on-a-sql-server-database-using-database

Comment: Yes. It took 10minutes to start after that and seemed to run ok for a bit. I restarted matlab and then it freezes with a java heap space error.

Comment: If you're running out of heap space, you could try this: http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/04/26/controlling-the-java-heap-size/

Comment: Did you change the matlabrc.m file or the startup.m file?

Comment: I think it has to do with a bug that happens to few people (like me, too) when running matlab under linux that is strongly attached to processing the "Current Folder" that you can see to the left when you start up Matlab. For me, I can see a "Processing..." underneath, with a "Cancel" link to the right. Clicking "Cancel" at least two times before it gets stuck seems to kill whatever it does and it works flawlessly afterwards. Repeat if you change the "Current Folder". Can anyone confirm that this works for them?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error always. And solved by increasing the Java Heap Memory that is requested and allocated by MATLAB from the Operating System. Maybe this can help you:

Go to **Home -> Preferences -> General -> Java Heap Memory** and shift the bar (Memory size that can be used by MATLAB.)

[image]

I hope this also works for you!